# Fazer o git passar pelo proxy

Tags: git, github, proxy

Eu estou configurando meu ambiente de trabalho aqui no serviço.

É windows 7 e possui um proxy com usuário e password.

Eu quero baixar um projeto do meu repositório no Github e preciso passar pelo proxy.

Estou fazendo tudo pelo *prompt* e eu cheguei no seguinte comando depois de pesquisar pela net:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:senh@nov4@proxy.servername.com.br:3128
```

Onde `senh@nov4` é um exemplo da minha senha.

o problema é que a minha senha possui `@` e não é possível trocar para uma senha sem caracteres especiais.

Fiz vários testes com alguns caracteres de escape e com aspas mas não consegui resolver essa questão do `@`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Troque o `@` da sua senha pelo [**Percent-encoding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) dele: `%40`, exemplo:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:senh%40nov%40@proxy.servername.com.br:3128
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Fica então o comando pra quem tiver problema com proxy e a resposta para minha dúvida. Valeu!

Comment: Para encontrar o endereço do proxy pelo chrome: `chrome://net-internals/#proxy`

Comment: Quando não mais quiser usar o proxy: `git config --global http.proxy ''`